# Appointment and Elected Offices of an Assembly under Robert's Rules

Tags: parliamentary-law, parliamentary-procedure

In most assemblies following Robert's Rules, there are elected positions, such as members of the executive board, chair and vice-chair of the assembly and so forth.
Now for this question, assume that an organization has two assemblies. Call them assembly A and B. All members of assembly A are also members of assembly B by virtue of office. However, there are also members who are just members of assembly B.
Assume that a member, C, of assembly B is the elected chair of assembly B.
Before the next election of members to assembly A, a vacancy is created in Assembly A. Member C receives a vacancy appointment to A.

My question is:
Does C continue to be the chair of assembly B or does the assembly need to hold another election for chair?

Answer (score 2):

Robert's Rules are one set of *standing orders* for the operation of a parliamentary-type assembly. They are not legally enforceable; they are simply "the way we do things 'round here."

What is legally enforceable are the organisations constitution and any resolutions passed in accordance with them.

If these prohibit a person who is on assembly A from being the chair of assembly B then, in the first instance, person C should resign or if they do not do so, a point of order should be raised to force this; and a new chair appointed in accordance with the constitution.

If there is no such prohibition, then they remain the chair until they are replaced in the normal course of business.